# ParseQueryAdapter, not showing results

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am attempting to use ParseQueryAdapter in my project, and have had not had any luck displaying results.

My goal is to get data from the ParseUser.  So, my model is extending ParseUser:

So I have a model:

```
@ParseClassName("Midwifefirm")
public class Midwifefirm extends ParseUser {



    public Midwifefirm() {
        // A default constructor is required.
    }

    //practice name
    public String getPracticeName() {
        return getString("practicename");
    }

    public void setPracticeName(String title) {
        put("title", title);
    }

    //education

    public String getEducation() {
        return getString("education");
    }

    public void setEducation(String education) {
        put("education", education);
    }

    //years in practice

    public String getYearsinPractice() {
        return getString("yearsinpractice");
    }

    public void setYearsinPractice(String yearsinpractice) {
        put("yearsinpractice", yearsinpractice);
    }

    //practice philosophy

    public String getPracticePhilosophy() {
        return getString("practicephilosophy");
    }

    public void setPracticePhilosophy(String practicephilosophy) {
        put("practicephilosophy", practicephilosophy);
    }
```

The adapter is here; I think the problem may be here with my query:

```
public class CustomMidwifeAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Midwifefirm> {


    public CustomMidwifeAdapter(Context context) {
        //query using Midwifefirm class, to get list of midwives
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Midwifefirm>() {
            public ParseQuery<Midwifefirm> create() {

                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Midwifefirm");
                query.whereEqualTo("userType", "midwife");


                return query;

            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Midwifefirm midwifefirm, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_midwife_result_list, null);

        }

        //use midwifefirm as item view/list

        super.getItemView(midwifefirm, view, parent);


        // find in layout the practice name
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);

        //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
        titleTextView.setText(midwifefirm.getPracticeName());

        // Add education view
        TextView EducationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.education);

        EducationView.setText(midwifefirm.getEducation());

        // Add yearsexperience view
        TextView ExperienceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yearsinpractice);
        ExperienceView.setText(midwifefirm.getYearsinPractice());

        //Add practice philosophy view
        TextView PracticePhilosophyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicephilosophy);
        PracticePhilosophyView.setText(midwifefirm.getPracticePhilosophy());


        return view;
    }

}
```

And here is my ListView;

```
public class MidwifeResultList extends ListActivity {


    private ParseQueryAdapter<Midwifefirm> mainAdapter;

    private CustomMidwifeAdapter midwifeListAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set display to listview, empty
        getListView().setClickable(false);




        //initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Midwifefirm>(this, Midwifefirm.class);
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicename");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("education");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("yearsinpractice");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicephilosophy");


        // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
        midwifeListAdapter = new CustomMidwifeAdapter(this);


        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);

        // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
       // listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMidwives);
      //  listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
      //  mainAdapter.loadObjects();

    }





}
```

I might be setting this up wrong..thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking at what you provided, I think it has to do with your query. You are querying the key "userType" but it doesn't appear that your subclass Midwifefirm has that key.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment you would get all the Midwife Objects using a query like this:

```
ParseQuery<Midwifefirm> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Midwifefirm.class); 
/* add any additional constraints to your query here */ 
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Midwifefirm>() { 
    @Override
    public void done(List<Midwifefirm> results, ParseException e) {

    } 
}
```

I believe Parse has a limit on the amount of objects you can get with a single query of 100 so you may have to look at ways you can increase that to fit your needs.

Comment: if I wanted to just list all users that have the data I defined in the midwife model, how would I specify that in a query?

Comment: query.whereEqaulTo("columnName", "yourCriteria");